# How can I achieve two different sessions for the same page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to have unique sessions for the same page in different tabs? Lets say I have in one tab this url https://www.test.com/test.aspx?id=123 and another tab with https://www.test.com/test.aspx?id=124. Each one has data loaded for their respective id. If I do something in the first tab that saves a value in a Session and then do the same with the second tab, if I switch to the first tab and make a PostBack (like calling an event that saves the information), the Session value from the second tab will be saved on the first. How can I avoid that?

Comment: That's not possible unless you do some customization around how you manage session.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Would you be so kind to provide me more information about that kind of customization?

Comment: Customization requires to create unique sessionKeys for the every new browser tab opened. For that the browser needs to send some information to the server so that server can use appropriate sessionKey for the specific browser tab. This entire approach will require you to write both server code (C#) and client code (javascript), and you will encounter many other use cases while implementing this customization. I would suggest to reevaluate your design and see if you can avoid using session...

Comment: Instead of saving it in a Session variable, maybe a HiddenField would work? Is it possible to hide the value from the HiddenField to not show it when inspecting an element (F12)? The reason to save it in a session was because the value was shown from the HiddenField when inspecting from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a big pain - and one that I wish a built in option/setting was available.

However, what often works VERY well?

You can use session to pass value(s) to a page, but ONCE you get on that page and the first page load (Is PostBack = False), then transfer/save the few passed values into ViewState. ViewState is quite much as easy and flexible as Session(), and it is a persisting set of values that is per page, and per tab. And it qiute much is the same if you used a bunch of hidden field controls for this anyway.

So, don't use the session() for persisting of values on a page, but use session() to pass values.

So now, you can have multiple pages open - and you only grabbed/used the session() to get values on first page load - after that, you code using ViewState. Now you want to be careful, since viewstate is browser side based - and you don't want to overload it. (put much data in Viewstate - since whatever you have in ViewState WILL MAKE round trips and lives in the browser - every post back will send this data from client side to server.

ViewState is also how asp.net manages all your controls. So if you have a bunch of text boxes - and do a post-back? you note that these controls values persist automatic for you. This works for you by asp.net using Viewstate. And Even if you have two of the same pages loaded - you note that text boxes etc. still persist for each of the pages.

Session() = for global types of values for that user - applies to all pages.

ViewState() = for per page values.

So, if you use session() to pass values to that page - say a new tab, then on first page load - transfer the few values to ViewState. Those values now are local to the one page, and are not effected by other tabs/pages open - even when pages are on the same page.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that I could use the viewstate to save an unique ID for that tab and build a session around that like Session("ViewState("uniqueid").ToString() + somestring") then?

Comment: There are a number of examples that do this as a solution. But then again, since all that code would need to be changed to use that unique id, then for just a few session() values, you might as well just use viewstate anyway.   But yes, you can generate a unique id, but both the origination page, and then the target page will have to deal with and use that uniquieID. It somewhat debatable if having to change all those pages is worth that effort vs adopting that session() is for global user values, and viewstate is for per page user values.

Comment: The problem then becomes how you generate that new ID. if a user clicks on remember password, then launching a new page will not trigger the logon code, or even the new sesion() event code. So, often it can still be hard to trigger the code that generates that new id. I suppose on first page landing, you can generate that ID, but then again, can you always control that first page landing to generate that ID? Or perhaps you generate the ID on page load, but now we back to having used viewstate being less work anyway.

Comment: okay, in that case I will opt to use the ViewState. If the information were to be sensitive, would you still recommend the use of ViewState?

Comment: Well, viewstate is encrypted. It quite hard to mess with. I will admit session() is of course much more secure and is server side only. I mean if you have some text boxes, hidden fields and say even a gridview display? Well, messing with viewstate would allow one to change any of these values. If this is a sensitive PK id to say some customer data, then I suppose the generated ID, and then putting the sensitive ID's in session() could be used for special cases.